# CGLContextObj to NSOpenGLView

Tags: opencv, cocoa, opengl

I am tinkering around with FxPlug recently, and I am wondering if it's possible to assign Motion 5/Final Cut Pro X's OpenGL rendering context to an NSOpenGLView loaded from a .xib file. My goal is to draw the current texture drawn in Final Cut's rendering context to my view and use that texture in OpenCV for image processing (via glReadPixels and other assorted jazz).

According to Apple's documentation, I can retrieve an FxRenderInfo struct that contains a CGLContextObj as a shared context. However, I am currently clueless on OpenGL context sharing, I mainly come from an OpenCV background, and most of the documentation in Apple's website is melting my brain at the moment. Is there a set of steps I can reference to in order to get my NSOpenGLView to access another rendering context's resources to draw in it's own context?

Answer (score 0):

Create a filter FxPlug and then in FCPX, apply that to the video track you're interested in. That filter will be handed a reference to the current frame (in VRAM if you declare that you support hardware and not software rendering), and you can then do whatever you want with its contents.

By the way, I'd recommend the fxplug mail list. (It's called a Pro Apps Dev list but really it's 99% FxPlug.)

https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/pro-apps-dev

Despite Apple's notorious secrecy, engineers on the Motion team are allowed to discuss, and are generally very helpful.